# How do I sequentially execute google visualization queries?

Tags: google-visualization

I have to execute a couple of queries in sequential and compare first and seconds query data and draw the table accordingly. I really clueless to find out where is an issue. I aware that, query execution is asynchronous. Please help.

```
//First Query
        function drawVisualization() {
            alert(" I am first");
            var sqlLastQuarterWeeks = "sql?tq=select MonthName, WeekStart, WeekEnd &sqlQueryID=last_quarter_weeks";
            var qryLastQuarterWeeks = new google.visualization.Query(sqlLastQuarterWeeks);
            qryLastQuarterWeeks.send(handleLastQuarterWeeksSqlQueryResponse);
        }
        function handleLastQuarterWeeksSqlQueryResponse(dataQueryLastQuarterWeeksResponse) {
            if (dataQueryLastQuarterWeeksResponse.isError()) {
                alert('Error in query: ' + dataQueryLastQuarterWeeksResponse.getMessage() + ' ' + dataQueryLastQuarterWeeksResponse.getDetailedMessage());
                return;
            }
            gblWeeksInformation = dataQueryLastQuarterWeeksResponse.getDataTable();

            drawLastQuarterWeeksAnalysis();

            //Second Query
            function drawLastQuarterWeeksAnalysis() {
                alert("I am second");
                var sqlLastQuarterWeeksAnalysis = "sql?tq=select Project, Passed, Failed, WeekStart, WeekEnd, WeekNumber &sqlQueryID=last_quarter_weeks_analysis";
                var qryLastQuarterWeeksAnalysis = new google.visualization.Query(sqlLastQuarterWeeksAnalysis);
                qryLastQuarterWeeksAnalysis.send(handleLastQuarterWeeksAnalysisSqlQueryResponse);
            }

            function handleLastQuarterWeeksAnalysisSqlQueryResponse(dataQueryLastQuarterWeeksAnalysisResponse) {
                if (dataQueryLastQuarterWeeksAnalysisResponse.isError()) {
                    alert('Error in query: ' + dataQueryLastQuarterWeeksAnalysisResponse.getMessage() + ' ' + dataQueryLastQuarterWeeksAnalysisResponse.getDetailedMessage());
                    return;
                }
                var dtLastQuarterWeeksAnalysis = dataQueryLastQuarterWeeksAnalysisResponse.getDataTable();
                alert(dtLastQuarterWeeksAnalysis.getNumberOfRows());
                var intNumberOfRows = dtLastQuarterWeeksAnalysis.getNumberOfRows();
                var intRowCounter;
                var tblWeekOverAnalysis = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                for (intRowCounter = 0; intRowCounter < WEEKLY_TESTS_TABLE_COLUMNS.length; intRowCounter++) {
                    if (WEEKLY_TESTS_TABLE_COLUMNS[intRowCounter] !== null) {
                        var colDataType = WEEKLY_TESTS_TABLE_COLUMNS[intRowCounter].split(':')[0];
                        var colDataValue = WEEKLY_TESTS_TABLE_COLUMNS[intRowCounter].split(':')[1];
                        tblWeekOverAnalysis.addColumn(colDataType, colDataValue);
                    }
                }
                var tblWeekOverAnalysisRow = new Array();
                for (intRowCounter = 0; intRowCounter < dtLastQuarterWeeksAnalysis.getNumberOfRows() ; intRowCount++) {
                    var strApplicationName = dtLastQuarterWeeksAnalysis.getValue(intRowCounter, 0);
                    tblWeekOverAnalysisRow[intRowCounter] = strApplicationName;
                    var strTestRunDates = dtLastQuarterWeeksAnalysis.getValue(intRowCounter, 3);
                    var arrTestRunDates = removeDuplicates(strTestRunDates);
                    var arrTestRunResults = getSortedTestRuns(strTestRunDates);
                    for (var intRowIterator = 0; intRowIterator < arrTestRunResults.length; intRowIterator++) {
                        var strTestRunDate = getTestRunOfDate(arrTestRunResults[intRowIterator], gblWeeksInformation);
                        tblWeekOverAnalysisRow[intRowCounter] = arrTestRunResults[intRowIterator];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

When I query the no of rows, I am getting the same answer for both executions. What am I missing here?

Solution tried based on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216141/google-visualization-how-to-call-and-draw-sequential-query-with-table): No Luck.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
        function drawVisualization() {
            var sqlQuery = "sql?tq=select MonthName, WeekStart, WeekEnd &sqlQueryID=last_quarter_weeks";
            var query1 = new google.visualization.Query(sqlQuery);

            query1.send(function (queryResponse) {
                drawQuestions(queryResponse);
            });

            var sqlQuery2 = "sql?tq=select Project, Passed, Failed, WeekStart, WeekEnd, WeekNumber &sqlQueryID=last_quarter_weeks_analysis";
            var query2 = new google.visualization.Query(sqlQuery2);

            query2.send(function (queryResponse) {
                drawQuestions(queryResponse);
            });

        }
        function drawQuestions(response) {
            alert(response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows());
            //answer is 11 & 11. expected is 11 & 180
        }
    </script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My apologies. I sorted out.

```
var sqlQuery2 = "sql?tq=select Project, Passed, Failed, WeekStart, WeekEnd, WeekNumber &sqlQueryID=last_quarter_weeks_analysis";
```

I was given wrong columns names which resulted in an error in query. This behavior does not allow to execute the second query and always returning the first.